# How can i draw a rectangle in android and put some text inside it and then place it?

Tags: android, draw

hi i have an activity and in the activity i have some buttons and textviews, and i would like to draw a rectangle with text inside. i saw some examples online but the all say to create my on view , override onDraw and the set this view as my layout, but i have my layout already.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView baramzona = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    baramzona.setText(R.string.baram_zona_textview);
    final Button pocniparking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonStart);
    final TextView momentalnazona = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);



    //momentalnazona.setText("Моментално се наоѓате во зоната");
    pocniparking.setText(R.string.btn_Start_Parking);
    pocniparking.setEnabled(false);

    }
  }
```

any ideas?

Comment: Creating your own view sounds overkill. I would look into whether you can set a background or a border on a TextView

Comment: found this http://www.androidpeople.com/android-textview-border/, going to give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a kind of a workaround but it suits my purpose. Basically you can put the TextView inside a table, set the table background for the outline and the margins for the size of the outline. Hope it helps.

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#55771B">
 <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01"
 android:id="@+id/TextView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
 android:layout_marginBottom="3px"
 android:layout_marginRight="3px"
 android:layout_marginTop="3px"
 android:background="#010101"/>
</TableLayout>
```